# Meaning of the continuous spectrum and the residual spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let's consider an **infinite** dimensional space $X$ and a linear operator $T$. The resolvent operator of $T$ is $R_\lambda (T) = (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$. A regular value $\lambda$ of $T$ is a complex number such that:

(R1) $R_\lambda(T)$ exists

(R2) $R_\lambda(T)$ is bounded

(R3) $R_\lambda(T)$ defined on a set which is **dense** in $X$

The resolvent set $\rho(T)$ consists of all regular values $\lambda$ of $T$. The complement $\sigma(T)=C-\rho(T)$ is the spectrum of $T$ and we may distinguish parts of the spectrum:

**point spectrum** (eigenvalues) $\sigma_p(T)$: (R1) isn't satisfied

**continuous spectrum** $\sigma_c(T)$: (R2) isn't satisfied, but (R1) and (R3) are satisfied

**residual spectrum** $\sigma_r(T)$: (R3) isn't satisfied, (R1) is satisfied, (R2) - doesn't matter

Please, help me to clarify a couple of points:

**Question 1:** The point spectrum consists of eigenvalues and exists in finite dimensional case. So its meaning seems to be the same as in a finite dimensional case (scaling of eigenvectors that roughly represent orientation of the distortion by $T$). What is the meaning of the continuous and the residual spectrum?

**Question 2:** Why do we care about `dense` in the definitions? I have found a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174697/why-do-we-distinguish-the-continuous-spectrum-and-the-residual-spectrum) but didn't get the exact answer from it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Question 1:** If $\lambda$ is in the continuous spectrum, then $R_{\lambda}(T)$ is unbounded. That means there exists a sequence $\{ x_n \}$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|R_{\lambda}(T)x_n\|\rightarrow\infty$. So, $y_n=\frac{1}{\|R_{\lambda}(T)x_n\|}R_{\lambda}(T)x_n$ is a sequence of unit vectors in $X$ such that $(T-\lambda I)y_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. It is typical to refer to this sequence $\{ y_n \}$ of unit vectors as an "approximate eigenvector."

The reason one refers to this as "continuous spectrum" Historically had nothing to do with continuity; such spectrum was found to fill a continuum, rather than being discrete. For example, the multiplication operator $(Mf)(x)=xf(x)$ defined on $L^2[0,1]$ has no eigenvalues, but $[0,1]$ is in the continuous spectrum of $M$. You can see this because the step function $f_{\lambda,\delta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\delta}}\chi_{[\lambda-\delta,\lambda+\delta]}$ is a unit vector for which
$$
         Mf_{\lambda,\delta} \approx \lambda f_{\lambda,\delta},
$$
in the sense that
$$
                \|(M-\lambda I)f_{\lambda,\delta}\|^2=\int_{\lambda-\delta}^{\lambda+\delta}(x-\lambda)^2f_{\lambda,\delta}^2dx \le 2\delta^2\|f_{\lambda,\delta}\|^2.
$$
So $\|(M-\lambda I)f_{\lambda,\delta}\|\rightarrow 0$ as $\delta\rightarrow 0$ while $\|f_{\lambda,\delta}\|=1$.

The same type of spectrum occurs for the differentiation operator $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ where you would like to identify $e^{isx}$ as an eigenvector with eigenvalue $s$, but it's not in the space. However, $s$ is in the continuous spectrum, a.k.a. approximate point spectrum. This is one of the earliest cases that motivated these definitions, where you could think of
$$
             F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(s)e^{isx}ds
$$
as a "continuous" (i.e. integral) sum of approximate eigenfunctions of the differentiation operator, with a coefficient function $c(s)$ defined on the continuum. And, when considered in $L^2$, the operator $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ has continuous spectrum $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question 2:** For your second question, you don't care about a dense domain for $R_{\lambda}(T)$ if it is bounded because you can then extended it to the whole space. And, if $T$ is closable, then the extension of $R_{\lambda}(T)$ and the closure of $T$ remain inverses of each other. However, if $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue and $T$ is closed, then $R_{\lambda}(T)$ must be unbounded, and you're basically stuck with a dense domain for $R_{\lambda}(T)$ because of the closed graph theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you please explain why the continuous spectrum is defined on a dense set in $X$? Could you tell a couple of words about the meaning of the residual spectrum?

Comment: @Konstantin : The continuous spectrum requires that you have an inverse that is unbounded. If $X$ is a complete space, then the inverse cannot be defined on the full space. It is standard to require the inverse to be defined on a dense subspace. If it is defined on a non-dense subspace, that falls into the miscellaneous category of residual spectrum. Residual should be regarded as the "left over" part of the spectrum.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be "And, if $T \color{red}{- \lambda I}$ is closable, then the extension of $R_{\lambda}(T)$ and the closure of $T \color{red}{- \lambda I}$ remain inverses of each other."?

Comment: Also you say: "The same type of spectrum occurs for the differentiation operator $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$" and later "when considered in $L^2$, the operator $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ has continuous spectrum $\mathbb{R}$".

Are you talking about two different versions of $L^2$?

Comment: Also isn't it true that we only have $\| f_{\delta, \lambda} \| = 1$ for $\lambda \in [\delta, 1 - \delta]$, otherwise $[0,1] \cap [\lambda - \delta, \lambda +\delta] \ne [\lambda - \delta, \lambda +\delta]$?

Comment: Just a little remark on the calculation of $\| (T - \lambda) f_{\lambda, \delta} \|$: one can use the substitution $u(x) := x - \lambda$ to easily explicitly calculate the integral, no need for an estimation:
$$
\frac{1}{2 \delta}\int_{\lambda - \delta}^{\lambda + \delta} (x - \lambda)^2 dx
= \frac{1}{2 \delta}\int_{- \delta}^{+ \delta} u^2 du
= \frac{1}{2 \delta} \cdot \frac{2 \delta^3}{3}
= \frac{\delta^2}{3}.
$$